# Creating 2-D Associative Array Using Template Operator

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Trying to define 2-D Associative Array, I wrote the template operator inside my class to make it closer to original array. This is my operator function.

```
template <class T, class U, class V>
T& TwoAssocDArray<T,U,V>::operator [](U input1)[](V input2) {
    for(int i=0; i<size(); i++)
        if(stack[i].key1 == input1 && stack[i].key2 == input2) 
                return stack[i].d;
    DataPack pack;
    pack.key1 = input1;
    pack.key2 = input2;
    stack.push_back(pack);
    return stack[size].d;
}
```

Class Interface,

```
#ifndef _DATASTRUCTURE_H_
#define _DATASTRUCTURE_H_

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T, class U, class V>
class TwoDAssocArray {

private:
    typedef struct _DataPack {
        T d;
        U key1;
        V key2;
    } DataPack;
    vector<DataPack> stack;

public:
    int size();
    bool isIn(U input1, V input2);
    bool add(T data, U input1, V input2);
    T get(U input1, V input2);
    T& operator [](U input1)[](V input2);
};

#endif
```

Then I tested it in main().

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    TwoDAssocArray<int, char*, char*> assocArr;

    assocArr["in1"]["in2"] = 2246001;
    cout << assocArr["in1"]["in2"] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After build and run, I found it didn't work, got a dozen of errors.
I assumed the main reason is template syntax with which I am not familiar.
I believe that a ton of errors always come from just a few syntax errors.

If anyone would help me, I would appreciate.

Comment: You should review your design: something like `arr[x][y]` requires  an `arr` object which supports the `[]` access and returns another object suitable for a second `[]` access.

Answer (score 0):

`T& operator [](U input1)[](V input2);`

You can't chain operators like that.  You may have seen that `operator[]` can only accept one argument as well, so you are out of luck for `T& operator [](U input1, V input2);`

From the title of this post it looks like you really want to be able to do:

`assocArr["in1"]["in2"] = 2246001;`

There is a way to get this functionality, and that is to implement it in one dimension:

```
template <class T, class U >
class MyArray {

private:
    struct DataPack {
        T d;
        U key1;
    };

    std::vector<DataPack> stack;

public:
    T& operator[]( U key );
};

int main( void )
{
  MyArray< int, char > one_dimension;
  one_dimension[ 'a' ]; // returns an int reference

  // Now the trick
  MyArray< MyArray< int, char >, char > two_dimensions;
  two_dimensions['a']; // returns a MyArray< int, char > reference
  two_dimensions['a']['b']; // returns an int reference
}
```

Also, note the way I'm declaring the struct, this is C++ my friend.  To add, don't use `char *`, use `const char *`.  Actually don't use `const char *`, use `std::string`.

`const char *` can be tested for equality, but you won't be comparing the content within the c-strings, you will be comparing the address of the pointers.